# Change the version of jQuery on a live site without access to the source

Tags: jquery, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to test if there would be any conflicts with changing the version of jQuery on an online website but don't have access to the source currently.

Is there any way to replace jQuery on-the-fly? I.e. with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the jQuery on the page temporarily by another version. To do so just execute [`include("jquery")`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Include) within Firebug's [Command Line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line). This will add the latest version of jQuery.

Though note that this only replaces the version on the client side, the server source stays untouched. Devtools like Firebug and the Chrome DevTools work on the client side and don't have access to the server file structure.

Comment: Awesome! "include("jquery")" was exactly what I was looking for. Thanx (P.S Sorry for the late reply)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try some sort of /etc/hosts/ hosts.ini change where on your local machine

//hostedloc/jquery/jquery.js

Now effectively points to your own version of the file.

Answer (score -1):

NO you can not , if you change it using firebug and Chrome Dev Tools you only see the difference in the current time when you refresh the page you will lose every changes you made

Comment: Of course you can change it, though only on the client side.

Comment: using firebug and Chrome Dev Tools you only see the difference in the current time when you refresh the page you will lose every changes you made ; mean client side